# How to pipe an observable data in to an array of observables?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

How to pipe an observable data in to an array of observables and map it with another observable inside?

Consider the following observable$:
`getItems$()`
returning the following data:

```
[
    {item: 1, value: 'one'},
    {item: 2, value: 'two'},
    {item: 3, value: 'three'},
    ...
]
```

So my question is that how to map the above observable in to a new observable such that inside it maps and unwraps another set of observables.

expected result:

````
[
    {item: 1, value: 'one', prop: 'someValueMappedFromAnotherObservableMethod1'},
    {item: 2, value: 'two',  prop: 'someValueMappedFromAnotherObservableMethod2'},
    {item: 3, value: 'three',  prop: 'someValueMappedFromAnotherObservableMethod3'},
    ...

// here someValueMappedFromAnotherObservableMethod1 is the value that should be obtained as a result of flatMapping observable inside the ```items.map()``` fn.
]
````

This is what I;ve tried. It's not working. Its not mapping and unwrapping observables inside the `items.map()`

```
    this.getItems$()
      .pipe(
        flatMap((items) =>
          items.map((item) => ({...item, prop: this.anotherMethodReturningObservableBasedOnItemValue$(item.value))}),
        ),
      )
      .subscribe(console.log);
```

But the above one is not working as expected. Let me know how to do this/

I also tried this way:

```
    this.getItems$()
      .pipe(
        flatMap((items) =>
          merge(items.map((item) => this.anotherMethodReturningObservableBasedOnItemValue$(item.value))).pipe(
            combineAll(),
          ),
        ),
      )
      .subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: This cannot be done using rxjs! Obviously, it's not possible.

Comment: It's not the purpose of rxjs.

Comment: In order to work this out the unwrapping have to be piped()!

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve what you want with this:

```js
this.getItems$()
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(items =>
      from(items)
        .pipe(
          mergeMap(item =>
            this.anotherMethodReturningObservableBasedOnItemValue$(item.value)
              .pipe(
                take(1), // toArray operator below requires all sources to complete
                map(prop => ({ ...item, prop })) // Combine new prop with existing props 
              )
          ),
          // Combine all items into single array
          toArray()
        )
    )
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: Can you please check the question one more time?

Comment: @mx_code Is this not producing the result that you want?

Comment: It works when I remove map and toArray(). But then it is returning them as separate items/observables and not as an array.

Comment: I think the toArray() is not working. Can you please check it once more?

Comment: I refactored the code a bit. The following is working without toArray()...

```this.getItems$()
      .pipe(
        mergeMap((items) =>
          from(items).pipe(mergeMap((item) => this.getFromAnotherObservable$(item.value))),
        ),
        toArray(),
      )
      .subscribe(console.log);``` This is working if I remove toArray(). But then the observables are separated & not as an array.

Comment: How can I combine them back again in to an array?

Comment: @mx_code `toArray` will only emit when the source observables complete. I assume then that the observable returned from `this.anotherMethodReturningObservableBasedOnItemValue$()` does not complete.

Comment: Is there any other way around?

Comment: What if this array ```[
    {item: 1, value: 'one'},
    {item: 2, value: 'two'},
    {item: 3, value: 'three'},
    ...
]``` is one nested inside another big object (which is an observable). (for the sake of simplicity I have isolated it inside the question).

Comment: @mx_code You can add a `take(1)` to the pipe of `this.anotherMethodReturningObservableBasedOnItemValue$()` to ensure that `toArray()` runs. I have updated my answer to show this.